# Placing an image to webcam feed using python - pygame in windows

Tags: python, opencv, pygame

i need to put a university uniform to a camera feed to place their faces on top of it and take a snapshot and upload it to our database. i need some help in my code written below.

- 1st problem: I cant call my webcam
- 2nd problem: my overlaying image isnt appearing right as i want it to be.(i need it to the bottom of the window...)

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaLv0wty9Ng) youtube tutorial.

```
import pygame, sys
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0", (640,480))
cam.start()

background=pygame.Surface((window.get_rect().width,                         
window.get_rect().height))
background.fill((0, 0, 0))
image=pygame.image.load('College Boy Medium.png')
image=image.convert()
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (720,640))
rect=image.get_rect()

while 1:
    image = cam.get_image()
    screen.blit(image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit
```

Comment: try to look at this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjKmgdrNCP0

Comment: @Rabbid76 no it doesnt solve it

Answer (score 0):

`Screen.blit(image,(0,0))` the *0,0* refers to the upper left of the image *box x y position*.

So *0,20* would place the image at *x position 0* and the y position down 20 pixels.